# Email Proxy Loop

Tags: windows, exchange-2003, smtp

I have an exchange server 2003 running in Windows 2003. I have an unnamed program that listened for incoming mail, signs it with DKIM and then should relay it back to the Exchange server.

I am a little lost on how to configure the SMTP in exchange 2003 system manager to relay sent mail through the proxy and then listen for it to come back signed. Once that is complete it is to send the mail to the specified address.

I know it involved relay and possibly connectors but the exact steps have eluded me.

Lets assume the proxy works perfect I just want to know how to relay to a specified IP and port then listen on another port when it comes back and then send it out.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is two send connectors for * (all domains) separating by permissions. The first would run at the higher priority, usable by all your users (but not anonymous). That connector will be configured to use the proxy program as a smarthost. The proxy program will submit things back to exchange through a receive connector allowing unauthenticated submission from localhost, and the second send connector for * that anonymous connections can deliver as normal.

Anything directly forwarded by Exchange (or submitted by anonymous SMTP) would bypass the proxy, but that may be desired. I supposed it'd be possible to reverse this with the default anonymous going to the proxy and it submitting things back as an authenticated user that has access to a higher-priority send connector, but that account would need to be authorized to send as all users

Comment: I set the smart host to the IP of the proxy and changed the port settings in advanced delivery . But DKIMPROXY cannot bind to it for some reason any ideas? I then created a second SMTP server for DKIMPROXY to forward mail through. Don't feel I need a connector? If I do how would that be setup? Any step by step walk through you can point me to?